# How can I prevent a form sending after refresh?

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I have a problem - After I fill in my form and click submit, it sends the information I have filled in, but when I refresh the page, information gets sent again. How can I prevent it? My php code looks like this:

```
<?php
function Form()
{
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $to = "Test@gmail.com";
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $text = $_POST['text'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];

        if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) &&
            isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) &&
            isset($_POST['text']) && !empty($_POST['text']) &&
            isset($_POST['subject']) && !empty($_POST['subject']) &&
            mail($to, $name, $email, $text, $subject))   
        {
            echo "<div class='success'>Message has been sent!</div>";
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
?>
```

So when a person fills in the form, it shouldn't resend the information after he refreshes the page. How can I do this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

as CBroe said you need to add a redirect to some other page.

```
if ( isset($_POST['name']) &&    !empty($_POST['name']) &&
 isset($_POST['email']) &&   !empty($_POST['email']) &&
 isset($_POST['text']) &&    !empty($_POST['text']) &&
 isset($_POST['subject']) && !empty($_POST['subject']) &&
 mail($to, $name, $email, $text, $subject))   
{


header('Location:thankyou.php');
}
```

and on thankyou.php

```
<?php
   echo "Message has been sent!";  //or whatever.
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`if ((isset($_POST['submit'])) && (!empty($_POST['name'])))`

A simple check to see if the user has inputted something into one of the fields.